# C# unable to delegate event handler with Task return type method

Tags: c#, reflection, task

I'm working to have a custom asynchronous event domain handling, when
I tried to create a delegate for **`Task HandleEvent(TEvent @event)`** method -that is responsible for async execution of events, once the return type is Task then I have a exception of

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because
>   its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of
>   the delegate type.'

```
public IDisposable RegisterHandler(object handler)
        {
            Contract.Requires(handler != null);

            var interfaceType = handler.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces()
                .SingleOrDefault(t => t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<>));

            if (interfaceType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Supplied parameter does not implement {0} interface.", nameof(IEventHandler<object>)));
            }

            var eventType = interfaceType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

            var stream = this.eventStreams[eventType];
            var streamType = stream.GetType();

            if (this.eventStreams == null)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("Event stream for '{0}' was not found.", eventType.Name));
            }

            var handleEvent = handler.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(IEventHandler<object>.HandleEvent));
            var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);

            var del = handleEvent.CreateDelegate(actionType, handler);

            var method = streamType.GetTypeInfo().GetMethods().First(
                t =>
                    t.Name == nameof(IEventStream<object>.Subscribe) &&
                    t.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault()?.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Action<>));

            return (IDisposable)method.Invoke(stream, new object[] { del });
        }
```

How can I create a delegate for the concerned method?

Comment: Common event delegate signature requires the return type to be "void".  Only "void".

Comment: @BionicCode any other possible solutions to achieve needed goal of using async task methods?

Comment: According to Microsoft, it's allowed to have an asynchronous method that returns void for the purpose of having async event handlers. You can write a custom event handler delegate by the way that returns a value, but the pattern doesn't support it as it won't make any sense when reconsidering the Observer pattern. As the pattern, which is also implemented in the .NET library, doesn't support it, your code will then break when used with common build-in event  handler delegates like EventHandler<T> (see your error).

Comment: Your fine to start an async operation that returns void in order to use it inside an event handler. Event handler doesn't support the "async". But keep in mind that an async method that returns void can't throw any exceptions that can be caught by the invocator. So making your delegate retun "void" should fix your problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index

Comment: Thanks for your advice, using asynchronous handling method with void return won't be efficient due to exception handling concerns which is very risky for my project, I think I'll replace the whole mechanism to use distributed and parallel processing concept.

Comment: Yes, it's better to trigger expensive operations from somewhere else than a a event handler. But it's not always possible, that's why you are allowed to do so, although the first intend was to restrict the return type to "Task" or "Task<T>" only.  Somehow the two patterns are clashing. No "void" return wanted in event handler delegates, but at the same time the event should be able to execute async, which in turn requires, to work as intended, to return a "Task" instance. You could expose a command on the type that observes the event. Or better implement "IObservable".

Comment: IObservable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx